# JS : Why does my do ... while loop is not exited?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to execute a do...while loop to try this code.

```
var savings, chequing, action;
savings = 1000;
chequing = 1000;
function checkAccounts() {
    alert("You have $" + savings + " in your savings and $" + chequing + " in your chequin account");
}

function withdrawal() {
    let amount = +prompt("How much would you like to withdraw?");
    //return the withdrawal value and store it in a variable called spending money
    return amount;
}

alert("Hello, welcome to the bank! What would you like to do?");
do {
    action = prompt("You can decide to see check your accounts (C), withdraw some money (W), or exit (E). Please choose one of those 3 actions");
    console.log(action);
    if (action === 'C' || action === 'c') {
        checkAccounts();
    } else if (action === 'W' || action === 'w') {
        let account = prompt("From which account would you like to withdraw some money? (S)avings or (C)hecking account");
        if (account === 'S' || account === 's') {
            let spendingMoney = withdrawal();
            savings -= spendingMoney;
        } else if (account === 'C' || account === 'c') {
            let spendingMoney = withdrawal();
            chequing -= spendingMoney;
        }
        alert("After this operation, here are the details of your account :");
        checkAccounts();
        console.log(action);
    }
    console.log(action);
} while (action !== 'E' || action !== 'e');
```

My goal is simply, when the user enters E when prompted, we exit the loop and meet the condition that while `action` is not E, we keep rolling. It does not work with the code above. I'm stuck with an infinite loop even when entered E.

I'm able to make it work if I create new `if` statement condition inside the loop, as `if action === 'E' {break}`. But then I don't understand why the while statement is not worth anything.

all the `console.log(action)` are for debugging purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this condition:

```
while (action !== 'E' || action !== 'e');
```

It'll always be `true`:

```js
const action = 'E';
const isFulfilled = action => action !== 'E' || action !== 'e';

console.log(isFulfilled('E'));
console.log(isFulfilled('e'));
console.log(isFulfilled('x'));
```

What you need is:

```
while (action.toLowerCase() !== 'e');
```

Or, less readably:

```
while (action !== 'E' && action !== 'e');
```

Comment: For some reasons, originally I only had capitalized letter option. Even at this point it was not working. I did not understand why... Not super clever question, but now it works. Thank you

Comment: I actually do not understand your first part of the answer... Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: The snippet demonstrates that no matter what the `action` is, the condition for your loop will evaluate to `true`.